# Lisp Find index in a list

Tags: lisp

So I have a list of integers and I'm trying to find the index where

```
list(i) > list(i+1)
```

I have the base cases where if the list is empty or length 1, it returns the list length, but I'm having trouble with actually traversing the list and keeping track of the index.

The code I have right now:

```
(defunc out-of-order (l)
(cond ((or (equal (length l) 0) (equal (length l) 1)) (length l))
    ; this is where the index search goes

)
```

Comment: Show the code you have right now. Also, if this is homework, mark it with the "homework" tag.

Comment: its just a small part of a homework function im writing, and there doesn't seem to be a homework tag for me to add

Comment: Is it suppose to be common-lisp?  What to return when no match is found?

Comment: it will return the length if no match is found also

Comment: @AlexD There is no [tag:homework] tag anymore.  See [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/225437).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a recursive function which takes an argument for "number of nodes already traversed". Within `out-of-order`, call that function with `0` as the number already traversed.

...Is that enough of a hint for you? Try again and see if you can get it.

**ANOTHER HINT**

```
 (defun out-of-order (lst)
   (out-of-order-rec lst 0))
 (defun out-of-order-rec (lst i)
   (if (or (endp lst) (endp (cdr lst)))
      ; something...
      (if (> (car lst) (car (cdr lst)))
         ; something...
         ; something...
         )))
```

Comment: so is the greater than check going to be in the helper or out-of-order?

Comment: ...How will the helper know how many times it needs to recurse?

Comment: i guess im just confused about the purpose of this helper and how to implement it

Comment: As you traverse recursively over the list, you need to keep track of how far you have already gone, so when you find a pair of elements which are out-of-order, you can return where you found them.

Comment: @JasonBoggess, the helper is necessary so that you can track the index you're looking at. The main function only takes one argument - the list - but the helper will take two - the list plus the index you're examining. It's possible to solve the problem without the helper, but then an implementation detail (the index argument) "leaks out" to the main function's signature.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sort of template outlining an approach to the problem.

```
(defun out-of-order (list)
  (labels ((recur (list index)
             (cond ((or #<list is empty> #<list only has one item>)
                    nil)
                   ((> #<the first item> #<the second item>)
                    index)
                   (t
                    (recur #<advance the recursion> #<increment the index>)))))
    (recur list 0)))
```

Think about the parts of the process (`#<these things>`) by themselves and also how they each contribute to the solution. Filling them in will lead you to the solution and I think also help you better understand recursive procedures.

Of course, please comment if there are any parts that are unclear.

If you're not familiar with [labels](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm), here's the same logic but using an external helper procedure instead:

```
(defun out-of-order-aux (list index)
  (cond ((or #<list is empty> #<list only has one item>)
         nil)
        ((> #<the first item> #<the second item>)
         index)
        (t
         (out-of-order-aux #<advance the recursion> #<increment the index>))))

(defun out-of-order (list)
  (out-of-order-aux list 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do this recursively.  In Common Lisp, it is more idiomatic to express this as an explicit loop.  That results in more portable code, since there is no requirement for a Common Lisp implementation to eliminate tail calls.

You can solve this with a simple `loop`.  You have three loop variables: the current element, the next element, and the current index.  As soon as you find a current and next element that satisfy the condition, you return the current index.

```
(defun find-downstep-index (list)
  (if (endp (rest list))
      (length list)
      (loop :for current-element :in list
            :for next-element :in (rest list)
            :for current-index :upfrom 0
            :when (> current-element next-element)
            :do (return-from find-downstep-index current-index)
            :finally (return (+ current-index 2)))))
```

(The special behaviour to return the length of the list if no such index is found causes the rather *ad hoc* initial guard and the addition of 2 at the end.  It would be more usual to return `nil` in this case, but perhaps there is some optimization in the surrounding use going on.)